# Criação e edição no Spring Framework

Tags: spring, formulário, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-jpa

Recentemente comecei a aprender Spring, junto do template engine Thymeleaf para exibição dos dados. Entretanto, venho enfrentando alguns problemas que não consigo solucionar:

1. No momento de editar a entidade Star Wars Movie, não consigo recuperar o campo "ReleaseDate" e setar no input de data do formulário. Quando eu mudo o tipo de input para text, este dado em específico acaba sendo exibido, mas gostaria que isso fosse feito em um input de data (que é o mais adequado).
2. Quando submeto o formulário "movieForm", tanto na criação, quanto na edição de um filme, há um problema de conversão também do campo "ReleaseDate". O Spring aponta que há incompatibilidade entre o tipo String (enviado do formulário) para o tipo Date (relacionado ao banco). Como poderia resolver esse problema de conversão?
3. Este problema está relacionado aos demais, e é um erro também na hora de submeter o formulário "movieForm". Não consigo salvar os dados enviados nem na operação de criação, e nem na de edição. Eu imagino que seja algum erro que cometi nas classes de Conversão (dentro do package converters), mas já estou procurando isso há dias e não consigo resolver.

**Star Wars Movie Controller**

```
    package example.starwars.controllers;

    import example.starwars.command.StarWarsMovieCommand;
    import example.starwars.services.StarWarsMoviesService;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    @Slf4j
    @Controller
    public class StarWarsMovieController {
    private StarWarsMoviesService starWarsMoviesService;

    @Autowired
    public StarWarsMovieController(StarWarsMoviesService starWarsMoviesService) {
        this.starWarsMoviesService = starWarsMoviesService;
    }

    @RequestMapping({"/", "", "index"})
    public String getIndexPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("movies", starWarsMoviesService.getStarWarsMovies());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/movie/{id}/show")
    public String showById(@PathVariable String id, Model model){
        log.debug("Getting Episode " + id + " page!");
        model.addAttribute("movie", starWarsMoviesService.getStarWarsMovie(Long.valueOf(id)));
        return "movie/show";
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/movie/new")
    public String newMovie(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("movie", new StarWarsMovieCommand());
        return "movie/movieform";
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{movieName}/{id}/edit")
    public String updateMovie(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String movieName, Model model) {
        log.debug("Editing " + movieName);
        model.addAttribute("movie", starWarsMoviesService.findCommandById(Long.valueOf(id)));
        return "movie/movieform";
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/movie/{id}/delete")
    public String deleteStarWarsMovie(@PathVariable String id){
        log.debug("Deleting Episode " + id);
        starWarsMoviesService.deleteStarWarsMovie(Long.valueOf(id));
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("movie")
    public String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute StarWarsMovieCommand starWarsMovieCommand) {
        StarWarsMovieCommand savedCommand = starWarsMoviesService.saveStarWarsMovieCommand(starWarsMovieCommand);
        return "redirect:/movie/" + savedCommand.getId() + "/show";
     }
   }
```

**Star Wars Movie Model**

```
package example.starwars.models;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
public class StarWarsMovie {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String movieName;
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
private Date releaseDate;
private Long boxOffice;

@ManyToOne
private Director director;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "starwars_starships",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "starship_id"))
private List<Starship> starships = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "starwars_characters",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "character_id"))
private List<Characters> characters = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**movieForm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Star Wars Movie Form</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form  th:object="${movie}" th:action="@{/movie/}">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
                <div class="pannel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1 class="panel-title">Star Wars Movie Information</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <label>Movie Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{movieName}"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <label>Release Date:</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{releaseDate}"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    <label>Box Office:</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" th:field="*{boxOffice}"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Também coloquei o projeto completo no **[Github](https://github.com/LucasDirani/StarWarsSpringDemoV2/tree/CRUD)**.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, quanto ao seu item 1 dataRelease:

Você pode usar a anotação DateTimeFormat para informar uma máscara na sua classe modelo. Já no seu html ao usar a thymeleaf você pode usar a máscara definida no modelo.

Anotação para colocar no Modelo:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Como utilizar a máscara no html:

```
th:field="*{{releaseDate}}"
```

Isso também deve resolver o item 2.

Uma boa prática é usar a anotação no modelo também a anotação para determinar o tipo de data do atributo.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Esses pequenos ajustes devem resolver seu problema.